# Running javascript code after loading content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried running my javascript code which is declarete in same file with ajax loadContent function. My problem is, after loading content, that function do not work.

I looked for solution, and i found .live() method in jQuery but I'm using 1.9 version which not support that now.

Here im loading spreadsheet to html doc:

```
var spreadsheet = $( 'div#item-list table > tbody' );

function loadContent(){
     $.post( 'ajaxRequest.php', { 'function' : 'loadData' } )
      .done( function( content ){
               spreadsheet.empty().append( content );
      });
    }
```

In this same file i have this code:
Before i loaded action buttons into spreadsheet, and now i would like do some action with form like "removerow"

```
$('input[name="removerow"]').on( "click" , function (){
            $.post( 'ajaxRequest.php', { 'function' : 'removerow', 'ID' : ID } )
          .done( function( result ){
                  alert(result);
          });
            return false;
        });
```

Problem is in javascript, not PHP, I'm sure that on 100%.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the delegated version of `on()` :

```
$('#item-list').on('click', 'input[name="removerow"]', function (){
   ...
});
```

Comment: It's working! :)

Do you have other solution to loading content, other method to do ? :)